# Getting a double word from binary data

Tags: c, binary

```
char * data = 0xFF000010FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

I want to get DOUBLE WORD in `data[1] (0x00000010)` and store it in var `int i`.

Would this do the trick?

```
int i = (int) data[1]+data[2]+data[3]+data[4]
```

Comment: The answer depends on whether your platform is big-endian or little-endian.  That will not work either way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to just add four bytes rather than position the values into the correct part of the integer.  Without specifying the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your platform, it's not possible to provide a final answer.

The general approach is to place each byte in the correct position of the int, something like this:

int i = 256 * 256 * 256 * data[0] + 256 * 256 * data[1] + 256 * data[2] + data[3]

(big endian example)

Note that the indices are 0-based, not 1-based as in your example.  The "base" in this example is 256 because each byte can represent 256 values.

To understand why this is so, consider the decimal number

5234

You can re-write that as:

5000 + 200 + 30 + 4

or 10 * 10 * 10 * 5 + 10 * 10 * 2 + 10 * 3 + 4

As you process data for each digit, you multiply the value by the-number-base-to-the-power-of-the-digit-position (rightmost digit for base 10 is 10^0, then 10^1, 10^2, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You must convert from your string into the actual data.  Consider using atol() or something similar to get the value in memory, then worry about editing it.